# Elegant way to create sequence of integers with decadic maximum of 59

Tags: r, sequence

Can you think of an elegant way to create a sequence of integers in R with decadic maximum of 59 (hmm sequence), with arbitrary starting/end points? Like this

> *715
>   716
>   ...
>   **759**
>   **800**
>   801
>   ...
>   830*

Comment: Do you mean this `n <- 3 ; rep(0:n*100, each = 60) + 1:60`?

Comment: @DarrenTsai thanks! What if I want an arbitrary starting/end point, e.g. 715 ... 830?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%%` to filter numbers whose remainders after divided by 100 less than or equal to 60.

```
x <- 715:830
x[x %% 100 <= 60]

#  [1] 715 716 717 718 719 720 721 722 723 724 725 726 727 728 729 730
# [17] 731 732 733 734 735 736 737 738 739 740 741 742 743 744 745 746
# [33] 747 748 749 750 751 752 753 754 755 756 757 758 759 760 800 801
# [49] 802 803 804 805 806 807 808 809 810 811 812 813 814 815 816 817
# [65] 818 819 820 821 822 823 824 825 826 827 828 829 830
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
x <- 715:830
x[!substr(x, nchar(x) - 1, nchar(x)) > 59]

#  [1] 715 716 717 718 719 720 721 722 723 724 725 726 727 728 729 730
# [17] 731 732 733 734 735 736 737 738 739 740 741 742 743 744 745 746
# [33] 747 748 749 750 751 752 753 754 755 756 757 758 759 800 801 802
# [49] 803 804 805 806 807 808 809 810 811 812 813 814 815 816 817 818
# [65] 819 820 821 822 823 824 825 826 827 828 829 830
```